# Mocking Submit of final-form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-final-form

I am attempting to test that a callback function is being called by submitting a form.  I have mocked an onSubmit function which is passed into react-final-form.  As shown in the codesandbox and below, I've got a simple form with an onSubmit callback.

```
export const MyForm = ({ onSubmit }) => (
  <Form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
        <Field
          label="Email"
          component={Input}
          name="email"
          type="email"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    )}
  />
);
```

When I simulate a click event on the button, I expect it to call the mocked function.

```
  it("should call onSubmit when the button is click", () => {
    const button = wrapper.find("button");
    expect(button.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    button.at(0).simulate("click");
    expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-silence-i0l2u-rff-i0l2u?file=/__tests__/App.test.js)

Comment: I think you might want to simulate 'submit' on the button and not click.

Comment: @Brenden thanks a lot for the quick reply.  I've update the codesandbox.  That fixes it, however I get a number of warning about **act** and **React-final-form** ```Warning: An update to ReactFinalForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).```.  It appears that Enzyme already applies act under the hood.  But even when updating the test with act it still has the warning- any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to simulate `submit` in order to submit the form.

As for the `Warning: An update to ReactFinalForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`, you are using a promise in your submit handler in the test which causes the form validation, submit, and state updates to be async.

`act()` provides a scope around expected component updates, and you will get this warning when an component does something outside of this scope. Since in the test the submit handler is async, the updates will happen outside of the `act()` function and will give you this error.

There are two ways to fix this, make the submit handler sync via `jest.fn()`.

```
const mockSubmit = jest.fn();
```

If you need to keep this async, you will need to act/await over a the submit promise. This would mean you would need to create a resolved promise value and have a mock function resolve it.

```
  const promise = Promise.resolve();
  const mockSubmit = jest.fn(() => promise);

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<MyForm onSubmit={mockSubmit} />);
  });

  it("should call onSubmit when the button is click 2", async () => {
    const button = wrapper.find("form");
    expect(button.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    button.at(0).simulate("submit");
    expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();

    await act(() => promise);
  });
```

Comment: @Brendon spot on, really appreciate the assistance - after changing to a regular jest mock function, the message has gone.  Makes all the sense in the world.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to use `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` and then `fireEvent.click(getByText('Submit'))`, [like this](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/master/src/ReactFinalForm.test.js#L460).